# ¿Como crear un enlace simbólico en versión 4++?

Tags: android

Mi pregunta surge por la razón de que quiero ser capas de crear un enlace simbolico de un archivo entre directorios, ejemplo crear un archivo en la carpeta "MisDatos" y quiero lograr que simbólicamente aparezca en la carpeta "Archivos actuales" sin tener que crear nuevamente el archivo solo mediante enlaces. Yo he encontrado un método que comente en mi pregunta:

> ¿Creación de un enlace simbólico a un archivo con la clase Os.symlink ()?

El método es funcional, pero el único error es que no me sirve por que es para android 5.0 en adelante y yo lo requiero para android 4.0 en android.
El codigo que utilice con el metodo Os.symlink es este:

```
File path=new File("/sdcard/Music.mp3");

String symLink=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
try {
    Os.symlink(path.getAbsolutePath(), symLink);
} catch (ErrnoException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

También he tratado con el método que incluye la clase Files de java pero creo que esta clase no se encuentra en java 8 porque cuando creo el método o la variable files no me crea la de java si no una variable de android referente a la media, el código que intente fue:

```
Files.createSymbolicLink("link o directorio deseado", "ruta original del archivo");
```

Pero como digo la clase Files de java no me la muestra si no una de android que no es la requerida porque no tiene el método deseado.
Esta información la encontré en: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/more-on-java-7-file-io/231601193

Si saben algún modo mediante código java o alguna otra forma por favor comentármelo.Gracias.

Comment: @abrahan puedes poner tu codigo? algun codigo que hayas intentado

Comment: Si se los muestro pero no me funciona porque es un método de Os.symlink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***No podes crear un enlace símbolico en la tarjeta SD*** porque esta utiliza un sistema de archivos FAT32 por lo general... 
Los enlaces simbólicos solo funcionan en NTFS, EXT2, 3 y 4.

Lo que intentas lamento decirte que es imposible...

Espero que se halla ayudado!

Comment: Ok gracias amigo, pero no habrá una forma de lograrlo con la memoria interna del dispositivo.Gracias

Comment: Claro que si! Puedes hacerlo creando una 2da participación en la tarjeta SD (la 1era FAT32 y la 2da EXT4[Sí es Android 4.4 o superior]) luego con la app link2sd puedes crear un script para montar esa segunda partición y ya podrás hacer enlaces simbólicos... Por lo general esa 2da participación se monta en /mnt/.

Comment: Ok , pero una pregunta como logro crearla desde mi aplicación.Gracias