# ¿En Android Es Posible Crear Enlaces Simbólicos?

Tags: java, android

Buenas a todos, He formulado esta pregunta con el fin de resolver el problema planteado.

En android es posible crear enlaces simbólicos mi pregunta surge porque necesito ser capas de crear un enlace simbólico a un archivo de la /sdcard con otro directorio en la misma /sdcard y debo realizar esto versiones de la 4.0 en adelante. Ya que en android no se acepta la clase Files que es con la cual se crea esto en java. Si conocen una forma de crearlo mediante java o de otra forma por favor comunicármelo Gracias.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como crear un enlace simbólico en versión 4++?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40907/como-crear-un-enlace-simb%c3%b3lico-en-versi%c3%b3n-4) En la respuesta aceptada pone que no es posible lo que quieres. Antes de hacer una pregunta puedes hacer una búsqueda para ver si ya está resuelta, y si no es tu caso mencionarla y decir qué la diferencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android es compatible con los enlaces simbólicos, pero ciertos sistemas de archivos FAT (por ejemplo RFS)  no lo hacen y no se puede crear enlaces simbólicos en esas particiones.

Si el dispositivo utiliza un sistema de archivos que soporte enlaces simbólicos (por ejemplo, ext2, ext3, ext4, yaffs2), entonces debería ser capaz de utilizar ln -s.